# Log the IP address of incoming requests in server.log file in GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4, httpservice, access-log

I want to log the IP address of incoming requests to my GlassFish's log. After doing some research, I found out how. But the problem here is that I learned how to log it in the access-log file. Is there any way to log the IP address in the server.log file?!

Comment: Do you want to log from inside of an application or do you want to log every request arriving at your GlassFish instance?

Comment: I want to log for every request.